# Is double-booting with Windows 7 viable with Ubuntu 14.04? Or does on have to be wiped, (Windows not pre-installed.)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, gnome, windows, windows-7

My mom's old i5 Ultrabook's Hard Drive died a year ago and now I want to install Windows 7 alongside Ubuntu so I can run MS Office (I prefer it to LibreOffice.) And Steam.  I also want to keep Ubuntu for coding and computer testing/development.  I heard my GNOME and GNU GRUB have issues with Windows 7 & 10.  Is this true?  If so, please help!

Answer (score 0):

No it isnt true u have to select the operating system at the begin of the boot of your computer thats all.

That can help you: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Comment: you should add this in comment